# How to pass a type (generic) to an annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I'd like to make an annotation that generates a method with a default return value. Because annotations can't be generic, I have to somehow get the return type of the method it annotates.

My goal is to replace the method with just `return <defaultReturnValue>` and default `defaultReturnValue` is depending on the value passed to the annotation.

`<?>` is the return type of the annotated method.

```
public @interface WhenDisabled{
    <?> defaultReturn();
}

@WhenDisabled(1)
int foo1() {
    // ... complicated calculation
    return result;
}

class MyClass {
    
}

@WhenDisabled(new MyClass())
MyClass foo2() {
    // ... complicated calculation
    return result;
}
```

In this example the body of `foo1` should be replaced by `return 1;` and the body of `foo2`should be replaced by `return new MyClass();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [JLS section 9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1), an annotation element's type (the return type of a method in an annotation type) may only be:

- A primitive type
- `String`
- `Class` or an invocation of `Class`
- An enum type
- An annotation type
- An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types.

You are probably best off encoding the information in a `String`.